# Get the value of the changed select in table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the values of the selected select
like the orderno of the changed row

The table looks like this [image]

if I change order no 1002 into sold

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from orders");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$row['orderno'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$row['total'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>';
           if($row['status'] == "sold")
           {
              echo '<select name = "status[]">';
                  echo '<option value = "sold" selected>Sold</option>';
                  echo '<option value = "cancelled">Cancelled</option>';
              echo '</select>';
           }
           else
           {
               echo '<select name = "status[]">';
                  echo '<option value = "sold">Sold</option>';
                  echo '<option value = "cancelled" selected>Cancelled</option>';
               echo '</select>';
           }
       echo '</td>
     echo </tr>';
}

if(isset($_POST['status']))
{
    //sample only
    echo "You change orderno ".$orderno_here." with the
    total of ".$total_of_order." into ".$selected_status_of_orderno_here;
}
```

There are many records in the table and the selects are the same

how do I get the values of the selected select

Comment: The selected value of *every* `<select>` element will be submitted with the form, irrespective of whether it changed from its default or not.  Given that you have named the form elements `status[]`, PHP will parse the submitted data into arrays—e.g. `$_POST['status'][0]`, `$_POST['status'][1]`, etc.  You can inspect the values of every submitted element and then decide what you wish to do with them.  However, you might find it easier if you index each form element by order number, e.g. `<select name="status[$orderno]">`.

Comment: ok, but how do I know which select status I changed using the orderno as index

Comment: One way might be to compare with the data currently in the database...

Answer (score 0):

Following your question, whatever i understood, according to that i am supposing you are getting data from **form** like tags in your page. If that is the case, you know that which value is changed to be reflected in db. So you can get that selected select from this. 
you can check the change through this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['element'])){
   //if this block executed, the <element> named element is changed
}
```

ignore this answer if this is not the case you are using in your code..